Implications for Hosts When Guests Exceed 90-Day Stay in Denmark
Would there be any consequences for the host if one of their guests overstayed in Denmark beyond the 90-day limit due to a misunderstanding about the visa expiry date?

How long an overstay? Did the host sign any kind of official invitation for submission with the visa application? Is the host a Danish citizen or a resident?

I'm not sure the question is on-topic on this site. Long term accommodation may have different laws (and requirement of check or registration to local authorities). We focus on the other side: as travellers, not as providers.
